# Driver classpath without submitted JARs - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have one node standalone cluster running DataStax Enterprise 4.8 with Spark 1.4.1 to which I submit my application in cluster mode like this:

```sh
dse spark-submit \
  --class MyApp \
  --master spark://MY-IP:6066 \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --packages LIST-OF-MY-DEPENDECIES \
  MyApp.jar
```

This seems to work as it should. It downloads all JARs for all transitive dependencsies to local Maven and starts my app however these JARs are not on the classpath.

```scala
object MyApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // This fails with: ClassNotFoundException
    getClass.getClassLoader.loadClass("akka.cluster.Cluster$")
  }
}
```

I have found out that the the classloader (`org.apache.spark.util.MutableURLClassLoader`) and its parents contain only standard static JARs provided by DataStax located under `/usr/share/dse` but none of my dependencies.

Another finding was, that Spark configuration property (and also system property) named `spark.jars` contains list of these JARs. How are these supposed to get to the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to give to all driver and executors access to your dependencies is to have them all packaged in a single **uber jar**.

Is this an option for you?

There few are options available to do this. If you are using sbt, the [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) is probably the most well know.

If you want to go with separated small Jars, `SparkContext.addjar(path: String)` might be what you need. You just have to make sure that your path is either on a shared file system (e.g., HDFS) or on a local directory that is common/replicated across all nodes in the cluster.

Comment: Note: I neer used the second approach, so let me know if there is a problem with it, I can take a closer look.

Comment: Uber jar is problematic due to conflicting resource files - overwriting reference.conf and also is getting quite large (100+MB). SparkContext.addjar does not solve my issue. The very first line of the main method requires a JAR on the classpath. But your advice is just a workaround. I would like to know why my approach doesn't work. Thanks